# XML Encoding Character Error when trying to Open in ALteryx

Tags: python, xml, character-encoding, encode, alteryx

I am using alteryx to edit an xml file and only replacing 5 numbers out of the whole 25k line file and everything is exactly the same but I get these characters in black on the left in for some reason when I export.

I kept everything the same export wise but these characters seem to throw off an error

The </ are black on the left in the  216 line and on the right they are blue
even when i edit them I cant make it go away...is there an encoding thing going ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moVNa.png)

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [mcve]. Hard to say what the problem could be from the image. Is the original xml well formed? Does the error reproduce if exported without modification?

Answer (score 0):

Just answered my question, my alteryx application is missing /> and  at the end of many rows at the end but couldnt see it all the way to the right ...I might have to come up with a way to solve this